# How can I improve a file line count counting lines according to categories in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

#### Code

```
def countqa(mdFile):
  result = []
  tailf=tail(mdFile)

  with open(mdFile, 'r') as f:
    qcounter = 0
    acount = 0
    for line in f:

        if line in '\n' or line in ' \n':
            continue

        if '####' in line:

            qcounter += 1
            if qcounter==2:
                result.append(acount)

            elif qcounter>1:
                result.append(acount)
 
            acount = 0
            continue
           
        acount += 1
        if line== tailf:
                result.append(acount)
            
  return teststr

print(countqa('example.md'))
```

#### mdFile:

```
#### Question 1?

This is the answer 1

second answer

#### Another question 2?

Another answer 2

#### Question 3?

Answer 1

Answer 2

The Answer 3
```

#### Result:

[213]

#### Expected output = Real Output

Count the number of questions and answers of a text file:

#### Preconditions

tail() returns the last line of the file.

Questions have #### at the front, answers (and code) not

#### What I want

How can it be improved? One issue is that the last line has to be unique, otherwise it gets a wrong result. The creation of the final list with the number of answers of each question is a hack, and difficult to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [regex](https://regex101.com/r/qzfD44/1):

```
txt='''\
#### Question 1?

This is the answer 1

second answer

#### Another question 2?

Another answer 2

#### Question 3?

Answer 1

Answer 2

The Answer 3'''

import re 

pat=re.compile(r'^####.*$\n([\s\S]*?)(?=^####|\Z)', flags=re.M)

>>> [sum(bool(line.strip()) for line in m.group(1).splitlines()) for m in pat.finditer(txt)]
[2, 1, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure of the purpose for `qcounter` so I just removed it. And removed some other stuff too. If you only expect it to return the amount of answers as a list then this code works. To prevent rows to be counted before the first question i check if there is an item in result before incrementing.

It's a bit more verbose than regex but I think it is easier to read and it's about three times faster.

```py
def countqa(mdFile):
    with open(mdFile, 'r') as f:
        file_content = file.read()
    result = []

    for line in file_content.split('\n'):
        line = line.strip()
        if line: # empty string is False
            if line.startswith('####'):
                result.append(0)
            elif result: # empty list is also False
                result[-1] += 1
    return result
```